# How to stop uitableview Scrolling When edit textview inside tableview cell and also increase size of the texview and cell acording text

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextview

My tableview goes down scroll when enter new line of textview.
Here is my cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
cell.textviewcomment.text =obj.str_comment;
cell.textviewcomment.delegate = self;
[cell.textviewcomment setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight];
```

and textViewDidChange Method

```
 CGPoint lastScrollOffset = tblmycomment.contentOffset;// Not working

     [tblmycomment beginUpdates];
        isEdit = true;
        curentcell=textView.tag;
        height = textView.contentSize.height+165;
        [tblmycomment endUpdates];

[tblmycomment setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, lastScrollOffset.y) animated: YES];// Not working
```

I try below code but also this code is not wrk proper

```
 NSIndexPath *pathc = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:curentcell inSection:0];
[tblmycomment selectRowAtIndexPath:pathc animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop];
```

Answer (score 1):

Below two ways i tried,

```
1.Use instead of the UITableViewController simply a UIViewController - set the datasource and delegate on your own.
2.Override the viewWillAppear method and don't call [super viewWillAppear: animated]
```

And then textview size increase according to connent text:

```
  -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return 78;
    }
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
   return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should scroll to the editing cell's frame otherwise your textView will be invisible.

```
UITableViewCell *editingCell; // your editing cell
[tblmycomment setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, CGRectGetMinY(editingCell.frame) animated: YES];
```